# Error in "Building a RESTful Web Service"

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I am a newbie in Spring Framework. I am studying a tutorial. It is at https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

below is my doing.
STS's version is 3.7.2
[Menu] - File - New - Spring starter project
Name : rest-service
Type : Gradle(STS)
Packaging : Jar
Java Version : 1.8
Group : com.example
Artifact : rest-service
Version : 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Description : Building a RESTful Web Service
Package : com.example
click [Next]
Not Select any Dependency.
click [Next]
Full Url : http://start.spring.io/starter.zip?name=rest-service2&groupId=com.example&artifactId=rest-service&version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT&description=Building+a+RESTful+Web+Service&packageName=com.example&type=gradle-project&packaging=jar&javaVersion=1.8&language=java&bootVersion=1.3.0.RELEASE
click [Finish]

copy and paste source
change "package hello;" to "package com.example;"

```
package com.example;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}



package com.example;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                        String.format(template, name));
    }
}



package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I clicked [Run As] - [Spring Boot App] but it is strange. If I download and run that project, it is well. If I make a project and type source, Error occurs. I thought that build.gradle has a problem. But I don't know exactly.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.0.RELEASE)

2015-12-02 15:51:50.706  INFO 4808 --- [           main] com.example.RestServiceApplication       : Starting RestServiceApplication on John-PC with PID 4808 (C:\Users\John\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.1.RELEASE\rest-service\bin started by John in C:\Users\John\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.1.RELEASE\rest-service)
2015-12-02 15:51:50.708  INFO 4808 --- [           main] com.example.RestServiceApplication       : No profiles are active
2015-12-02 15:51:50.744  INFO 4808 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@45afc369: startup date [Wed Dec 02 15:51:50 KST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-12-02 15:51:51.334  INFO 4808 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-12-02 15:51:51.343  INFO 4808 --- [           main] com.example.RestServiceApplication       : Started RestServiceApplication in 0.818 seconds (JVM running for 1.268)
2015-12-02 15:51:51.343  INFO 4808 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@45afc369: startup date [Wed Dec 02 15:51:50 KST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-12-02 15:51:51.345  INFO 4808 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: There is no error in the logs so what is the issue? Make sure that you have `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency.

Comment: @M. Deinum Thank you for your help. I don't know spring framework, gradle and maven well. I saw [Configure] - [Convert to Maven Project] and convert to maven. Seeing other wrightings and modifying pom.xml, this project works well.